# Powershell: How do I get all users that have logged into one computer for the day?

Tags: powershell

Need a list of all users that are on and were on a computer. So it will show all the users log in, log off, and locked status.
The only code I have so far shows only currently logged in users and locked status, but not individuals that had logged on previously, but are now logged off.

`query user /server:$Server`

I do not need system users/processes.

Comment: You will have to query the event log for this kind of information. Please use the search either here on SO or in your favorite search engine to look for solutions. Questions like this have been asked and answered a thousand times already.

Answer (score 0):

Logon events are audited via the Security event log:

```
'computer-01', 'computer-02' |
ForEach-Object {
 Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -Logname 'security' -MaxEvents 100
    –FilterXPath '*[System[EventID=4624]]'
}
```

...with the relevant computer names, and with these (System) event id's:

| Event ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 4624 | An account was successfully logged on. |
| 4625 | An account failed to log on. |
| 4740 | A user account was locked out. |

Comment: You should remove the line break from the `Get-WinEvent` command line as it will return an error. ;-)